# Sorting Alphabetically in PHP from Database

Tags: php, android, mysql, sorting, alphabetical

I'm trying to sort a list alphabetically, this list is taken from a MySQL Database but I can only arrange the information in ascending or descending order. This is the code I'm currently using:

```
if(isset($_GET['cat_id']))
{
    $cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];    
    $query="SELECT sub_cat_id,sub_cat_name FROM tbl_sub_category WHERE cat_id='". $cat_id."' ORDER BY tbl_sub_category.sub_cat_id DESC LIMIT $number_of_posts";         
}
else if(isset($_GET['sub_cat_id']))
{            
    $sub_cat_id=$_GET['sub_cat_id'];    
    $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_directory WHERE d_subcat_id='". $sub_cat_id."' ORDER BY tbl_directory.d_id DESC LIMIT $number_of_posts";
}
else if(isset($_GET['sub_sub_cat_id']))
{            
    $sub_sub_cat_id=$_GET['sub_sub_cat_id'];        
}
else if(isset($_GET['directory_id']))
{            
    $directory_id=$_GET['directory_id'];        
    $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_directory WHERE d_id='". $directory_id."'";       
}
else
{   
    $query="SELECT cid,category_name,category_image FROM tbl_category ORDER BY tbl_category.cid DESC LIMIT $number_of_posts";
}
```

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: Why tagged android??

Comment: Use ORDER BY with the 'name'-field you want to sort, not the 'id' field.

$query="SELECT ... FROM tbl_category ORDER BY tbl_category.category_name DESC ...";

Comment: This is an android app thats retrieving information from a database

Comment: Thanks usermesam0023 that got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort by name, not by id.

Note: Put the appropriate field names where necessary.

Corrected code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['cat_id'])) {
  $cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];      
  $query="SELECT sub_cat_id,sub_cat_name FROM tbl_sub_category WHERE cat_id='". $cat_id."' ORDER BY tbl_sub_category.sub_cat_name DESC LIMIT $number_of_posts";
}
else if(isset($_GET['sub_cat_id'])) {
  $sub_cat_id=$_GET['sub_cat_id'];        
  $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_directory WHERE d_subcat_id='". $sub_cat_id."' ORDER BY tbl_directory.d_NAME_FIELD DESC LIMIT $number_of_posts";
}
else if(isset($_GET['sub_sub_cat_id'])) {
  $sub_sub_cat_id=$_GET['sub_sub_cat_id'];        
}
else if(isset($_GET['directory_id'])) {
  $directory_id=$_GET['directory_id'];      
  $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_directory WHERE d_id='". $directory_id."'";
}
else {   
  $query="SELECT cid,category_name,category_image FROM tbl_category ORDER BY tbl_category.category)name DESC LIMIT $number_of_posts";
}
```

Comment: That actually did not work, now I'm not being able to retrieve my database info.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work thanks to usermesam0023 just changed this line `ORDER BY tbl_directory.directory_name` instead of `directory_id`.